# EGREP command that prints all lines which contain a substring of four letters

Tags: regex, unix

Having trouble creating an egrep command that prints all lines from the standard input which contain a substring of 4 letters that appear three times. For example,
the line:

*Consider this line, and the word side one sideline*

should be printed because it contains substring ‘side’ three times.

What I have so far is `egrep ([a-zA-Z]{4})` which is only showing parts of the string with four consecutive letters. My objective is to return the entire line whereas it contains "side" 3 times. I am still new to regular expressions. Can anyone explain to me how I could go about fixing this expression?

Comment: Do you mean `grep -E '([[:alpha:]]{4})(.*\1){2}'`?

Comment: `([[:alpha:]]{4})(.*\1){2}` finds 4 letters and two repetitions of this exact substring to the right (and they may be separated with any 0+ chars).

Comment: Ah I see. Yes that is what I'm trying to achieve, within the word 'consider' is the substring 'side' which also appears twice more in this particular file. I have tried this command and the command does not return anything. To my understanding, that command is looking for a group of 4 letters followed by 2 repetitions of that substring, regardless of the char's in between. If that is true, then I don't understand why the command isnt returning the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for

```
grep -E '([[:alpha:]]{4})(.*\1){2}' file
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xxN3qC/1) and [an online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/auzREj).

The expression finds four consecutive letters and two repetitions of this exact substring to the right that may be separated with any 0+ chars.

**Details**

- `([[:alpha:]]{4})`  - a capturing group #1: four (due to the range/interval/limiting quantifier `{4}`) letters (`[[:alpha:]]` matches any letter)
- `(.*\1){2}` - two repetitions of:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars
  - `\1` - the value captured into Group 1 (=the text matched with `[[:alpha:]]{4}`).